# Deleting a question while someone is in the middle of answering it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Mild annoyance here, but does a user get prompted that someone is in the process of answering a question before they voluntarily delete it?

I was just in the middle of answering a decent question when it was deleted as I was proofing it.

Being warned or prevented from be able to delete in this scenario would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question owner deletions are indeed prevented when there is an answer with at least one upvote, or more than one answer.

However, we can't prevent self-deletion in the case where there are not yet any answers; the owner has the right to withdraw their question if, say, it was a goofy mistake on their part, etc.